# Why is it redirecting wrongly

Tags: php, html, redirect, uri

I have a table form:

```
$html.='<div class="grid-round">
            <form method="post action="">
                <table class="grid-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" ></th>
                        <th>name</th>
                        <th>type</th>
                        <th>date</th>
                        <th>Stat</th>
                    </tr>
                     ...
                </table>
                <button>save</button>
            </form>
</div>';
```

The page where it is placed is on address:

www.example.com/admin?cid=53&user_id=10

but when I press the button it redirects me on:

www.example.com/admin

I have putted in `action=" '.$SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ].' "` but it also did not help. Can somebody advise what to do or where is the problem?

Comment: You miss a closing quote after `post`. Typo?

Comment: if you don't want to submit your page, you can add 'type="button"' to your button, otherwise the button will always submit to your action link

Comment: @Bart Friederichs yep))) you are right) thanks)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a quote after `method="post`:

```
$html.='<div class="grid-round">
            <form method="post" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an underscore after $ and a double quote after post

Try:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" >
     ......
     ......
     ......';
```